# Getting error while using CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey API to extract private key from PFX file

Tags: certificate, cryptoapi, pfx

We are developing VC++ application using Crypto APIs for windows 7 OS.
We are using CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey API to extract private key from PFX file  .

On executind this API, we are getting below error:

0X8009200B(private key error)

PFX file used with this API has multi layer certificate(root and intermediate).
When we use such PFX file, error comes.
And if we use PFX having single layer certificate that time it works.

So please suggest the reason for its failing.

Note: PFX file is provided by third party vendor(like symantec).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you import your PFX certificate, you will have to enumerate the certificate's present in the store. Then look for a certificate that has a private key. Now try and acquire the one with private key.